# bash command runs through cli fine but not running inside python script

Tags: python, linux, bash, python-2.7

Here is python script it is program which gets current INTERNET speed from cli and saves it in a python variable

```
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen

def cmdline(command):
    process = Popen(args=command,stdout=PIPE,shell=True)
    return process.communicate()[0]

aa=(cmdline("awk '{if(l1){print ($2-l1)/1024,($10-l2)/1024} else{l1=$2; l2=$10;}}' <(grep eth0 /proc/net/dev) <(sleep 1); <(grep eth0 /proc/net/dev)"))

print(str(aa))
```

gives error

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Comment: missing the python shebang?

Comment: why are you calling awk from python when python can do the same thing.

Comment: how can this be done without awk

Comment: What do you want to achieve?
Check this: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspeedtest

Comment: I don't know much Python, hence just a comment not an answer, but I think that Python uses `/bin/sh` rather than `bash` as the shell and I think `<(...)` is a `bash-ism`.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That is exactly right on both points.

Comment: @chepner Thank you for your thoughts - please feel free to go ahead and suggest an alternative form as an answer, if you wish. I am on the limits of my knowledge and don't wish to mislead or suggest sub-optimal answers :-)

Comment: i am writing this script to shutdown the my VPS server upon DDOS. Thats why i was writing this script. Thanks you all for viewing it

Answer (score 2):

`Popen` executes its command by default with `/bin/sh`, the POSIX shell. It does not recognize the `bash` extension `<(...)`, which leads to your error. The quickest fix is to specify that you want to use `/bin/bash` as the shell:

```
process = Popen(args=command, stdout=PIPE, shell=True, executable="/bin/bash")
```

A better solution would be to stick with a POSIX-compatible command, so that your Python script doesn't rely on `bash` being installed in any particular location, or at all. Something like

```
cmd = '''{
  grep eth0 /proc/net/dev
  sleep 1
  grep eth0 /proc/net/dev
  } | awk '{if(l1){print ($2-l1)/1024,($10-l2)/1024} else{l1=$2; l2=$10;}}'
'''


aa=(cmdline(cmd))
```

The *best* solution would be to figure out how to do what you want in Python itself, instead of embedding a shell script.

Comment: Its still not working man, thanks for you help but now its giving me this error.
/bin/sh: 5: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string